# angular2-powerbi : Configuration Issue You must specify a type in the configuration or as an attribute such as 'powerbi-type="report"'

Tags: angular, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to use the PowerBI-Angular2 to display the Power BI embedded one and getting the below error.

```
errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Attempted to embed using config {"accessToken":"xxxxx","tokenType":0,"embedUrl":"https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed?reportId=xxx","id":"xxxxx"} on element

, but could not determine what type of component to embed. You must specify a type in the configuration or as an attribute such as 'powerbi-type="report"'.
at Service.embedNew (service.ts:227)
at Service.embed (service.ts:210)
at PowerBIComponentComponent.embed (angular2-powerbi.umd.js:101)
at PowerBIComponentComponent.ngOnChanges (angular2-powerbi.umd.js:45)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:272)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:505)
at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:443)
at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (services.ts:348)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (xxxComponent.ngfactory.js:971)
at Object.updateDirectives (services.ts:87)
```

I am using Angular 4 x and here is the system configuration mapping.

```
'angular2-powerbi': 'npm:angular2-powerbi/angular2-powerbi.umd.js',
'traceur': 'npm:traceur/src/traceur.js',
'powerbi-client': 'npm:powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js',
```

on HTML side

```
 <powerbi-component [embedUrl]="reportEmbedUrl"
                                       [accessToken]="embedToken" type="report" [id]="reportId"></powerbi-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the value for type as "report" in a variable when you set the values for reportEmbedUrl and access token. As the power bi checks for the changed value everytime it loads the report.